# "A local variable named 'Model' cannot be declared in this scope" error on production hosting. What's wrong with the code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, web-config

Following Razor code is working fine when debugged using Visual Studio but on the production server, it is showing `A local variable named 'Model' cannot be declared in this scope.` error.

```
<li><b>@Html.LabelFor(Model=>Model.RegisteredName)</b>&nbsp;@Model.RegisteredName</li>
```

On local system I am  adding following lines inside `<system.codedom>` section in web.config:

```
<compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
```

And when I remove this it shows the same error when debugged from Visual Studio.

When I add these lines to the production server, it is showing me this error:

```
This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator
```

Comment: Change it to `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisteredName)` - or anything else other than capital `M` Model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the variable of lamba from `Model` to `model`.
Like this:

`<li><b> @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.RegisteredName)</b>&nbsp; @Model.RegisteredName</li>`